# Slash Commands Attachments

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

for those who still use v12, I updated the function a while ago, it sends files with it.

```js
    async function send(interaction, content) {
      const { data, files } = await Discord.APIMessage.create(client.channels.resolve(interaction.channel_id), content)
    .resolveData()
    .resolveFiles();
      
    return client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
      data: {
        type: 4,
          data: { ...data, files: files }
        }, files
    });
  }
```

could someone help me with this function, i am working with slash commands (commands with /) and i am not able to send files, nor files in embeds.  I would not like to know how to adapt to include files, or if you can already send as you are going to send.  (I am very noob still in question of these commands)

```js
async function msg(i, c) {
  const m = await Discord.APIMessage.create(client.channels.resolve(i.channel_id), c)
  .resolveData()
  .resolveFiles();

  return { ...m.data, files: m.files }
}
```

**i = interaction, c = content**

this function is part of a handler of mine, it works to send embeds and collect arguments, but I wanted to implement image manipulation in my commands.

Comment: Hi, i'm having the same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I left of site, if i was online at the time i would have send my github which i managed tô salve. But now it's on v13

Comment: https://github.com/Inkeee/Tutorial-Discord-Bot